# Yii2 custom action column issue

Tags: gridview, yii2

I wrote this code for a custom action column:

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 
'template' => '{view} {update} {asign}',
'buttons' => [
    'asign' => function($url, $model, $key) {

        $url = Url::to(['events/asignevent', 'IdE' => $model['IdEvent'] ]);

        return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>', $url, [
            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Asign'),
        ]);

    }
],

],
```

And works well, it shows the icon and when I click it, it directs me to the correct page. The problem is after that, if I want to go back to the previous page (with the back button of the browser) I finish on the previous of the previous page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove `'enablePushState'=>false` from the `pjax` configurations.

If you see into [**`PJAX DOCS`**](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) you will see that the key `push` uses [**`pushState`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) to add a browser history entry upon navigation, which is not happening in your case due to `"enablePushState"=>false`.

That is why when you click on the link `Assign` and after your page is redirected you are not taken back to the same page number according to the pagination that you were previously on because the browser has no record or traces of that page in the history.

Comment: You're totally right Muhammad. Thanks, you are the best!